# Php wont echo html from database

Tags: php, html, echo

```
$stmtcon = $mysqli->prepare("Select content From tblcontent Where contentid =?");
$stmtcon->bind_param('s', $loadcontent);
$stmtcon->execute();
$stmtcon->bind_result($htmlcontent);
$stmtcon->fetch();
$stmtcon->close();

echo $htmlcontent;
```

The code works perfectly on my computer, but wont echo on the server I use. If i do an isset on the htmlcontent it comes back as true. Every other element on the page loads.

Is there anything in the settings, security wise that could be blocking this echo? the content contains html.

Thanks.

edit - I changed the type of the field to text from longtext, is there any reason why longtext wouldnt work, thanks for replies already ^_^

Comment: Make sure it is connecting correctly to the mysql server, and check for mysql errors.

Comment: You could do `var_dump($htmlcontent)`to see exactly what is in $htmlcontent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the variable htmlcontent was holding nothing, I changed the field type from longtext to text and it works now, so for some reason longtext wont work, It's fixed but does anyone know why longtext wouldnt work?

Comment: Can it be something related with buffering? Can you put a $stmtcon->store_result() before the bind_result and try?

Comment: That fixes it as a longtext anders, nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Can it be something related with buffering? 
Can you put a $stmtcon->store_result() before the bind_result and try?